# Insert content after X number of paragraphs, excluding paragraphs inside a certain div class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the following code to insert content after the 8th paragraph on the page:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'hbg_insert_post_ads_8' );
function hbg_insert_post_ads_8( $content ) {

    $ad_code =  hbg_ad_code();

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return hbg_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 8, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function hbg_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

**However** I would like to exclude paragraphs that are within a certain div so the content is not placed within my highlight or call out boxes.  Perhaps don't count the `<p>`'s or place the code within a div that has the class "no-ads".  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML into DOM.
Then walk through the DOM and add new element wherever you want.
Then convert DOM back to HTML

Here is an exmaple of the function to walk through the nodes:

```
function insert_node($parent, $elements_to_ignore, & $at, $newNode, $nested_level){
    if(!property_exists($parent,"childNodes") || $parent->childNodes === NULL ){
    return;
    }
    foreach($parent->childNodes as $element ){
    //process childs

    if( get_class($element) != "DOMElement"){
        continue;
    }

    if(!property_exists($element,"tagName")){
        continue;
    }
    $tag = $element->tagName;
    $class = $element->getAttribute("class");
    if(in_array($class, $elements_to_ignore)){
        echo "ignoring node $class\n";
        continue;
    }
    echo str_repeat("-",$nested_level)."-> tagName[$at] :  class: ".get_class($element)." ".$tag."\n";
    if($tag == "p"){
        $at--;
        if($at==0){
            echo "adding node\n";
            $parent->insertBefore($newNode,$element);
        }
    }
    insert_node($element, $elements_to_ignore, $at,$newNode,$nested_level+1);

    }
}
```

And here is an example how to use it:

```
$body="<p>1</p><p>2</p><div class=\"bad-class1\"><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p></div><div class=\"good-class\"><p>6</p></div><p>7</p><a href=\"blahblah\">sdsds</a><p>8</p>";

$dom =  new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);

$root_element = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

$new_element = new DOMElement("p","extra text");
$at = 4;// insert new element before 4-th paragraph
insert_node($root_element,["bad-class1","no-ads"], $at, $new_element,0);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```